# Unable to deploy custom labels via SFDX metadata deployment

Tags: salesforcedx, customlabel, deployment-error

We deploy custom labels in our org via SFDX metadata deployment. So we use 'CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml' file to store and deploy labels to our higher orgs.

Since last few days we are facing this issue that whenever we add any new label to this file and try to deploy, we face issue which says - `'Invalid reference c.CustomLabelName of type label in file CustomLabelUtility.js'`

Can anyone help us in understanding why we are facing this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you checked the CustomLabelUtility component that is throwing the error to check that there isn't a label that has been removed from the labels file but is still in that component?

Comment: yes, checked, it is there. Thanks.